TS compile error after extending Express.User via d.ts file
I have a project with Express and Passport, and I'm extending Express.User via a d.ts file like so:
import IUser from "./src/interfaces/userInterface";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface User extends IUser {}
  }
}

In my index.ts file I added a mock check for the session and user data that the backend receives:
  app.get('/auth-check', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log('SESSION => ', req.session);
    console.log('USER => ', req.user);
    const userId = req.user?._id ?? undefined;
    if (userId) {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(401);
    }
  });

I'm running into a compile error: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'.
However, the IDE shows no errors when I type req.user?._id, in fact it can autocomplete to any property of IUser. If I leave only the console logs, it prints req.user with the mock data I send from the client, including the _id. If I remove the d.ts file, the IDE will show the same "property does not exist" error, so that part seems to be working as intended.
These are the contents of my tsconfig file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types", "src/interfaces"],
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "src/**/*", "src/interfaces/expressExtend.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

I've looked at different solutions in similar questions but so far nothing has worked for me. Things that I've tried:

Specifying the file path to the d.ts file in "typeRoots", not just
the path to the folder
Specifying the file path to the d.ts file in "include"
Check whether Passport user is overwriting my custom type (doesn't seem to be the case)
Moved the d.ts file to the root folder, updating all references to it
On the d.ts file removing the 'export' in 'export interface User...'. Also adding a separate empty 'export {}'
Importing the d.ts file directly in index.ts

Nothing seems to work, I always get the same property does not exist on type error.

For anyone with the same problem as me, what solved it was to do it the other way around. Instead of modifying Express.User to extend my custom IUser interface, I defined IUser as an extension of Express.User:
// user.interface.ts
interface IUser extends Express.User {
  _id: string;
  ...
}

I then used type assertion when needed:
// index.ts
const user = req.user as IUser;

Is not elegant, and I still think there must be a way to do it the other way around so we don't have to do type assertion every time, but at least it's working now.
